# If $x_n→ x$ in $\ell^2$ then $\lim_{n→\infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$ if $f$ is continous?

Tags: convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N} \subset \ell^2$ with component wise limit $x \in \ell^2$. Let be $f:\ell^2→\ell^2$ is continous.

Is it true that:

$$\lim_{n→\infty}f(x_n)=f(\lim_{n→\infty} x_n)=f(x)? \tag C$$

In my opinion, it is not true since continuity claims $\lim_{n→ \infty}x_n=x$ so convergence with respect to a norm and not only component-wise.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by component-wise limit?

Comment: since $x_n \in \ell^2$ it is a infinite-dimensional vector. By component-wise I mean every component of his infinite-dimensional vector converges to a limit of the components of $x$.

Comment: What is the convergence on $(C)$ that you want? component-wise again?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like to have, but I am not sure if this makes sense. So, since $f$ continuous that means for all $x \in \ell^2$, $\varepsilon >0$ and there is a $\delta >0$ such that for all $x _0\in \ell^2$ it holds $\|x-x_0\|_{\ell^2} < \delta \Rightarrow \|f(x)-f(x_0)\|_{\ell^2}<\varepsilon$.

By definition of the $\ell^2$-norm that means $\sum_{k \ge 1} |x_n^{(k)}-x^{(k)}| < \delta$ and $\sum_{k \ge 1}| (f(x_n))^{(k)}-(f(x))^{(k)}| < \varepsilon$. Thus every summand of both sum must be abritraly small so we got component wise continuiy, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't true. For example you can use $f(x) = x$, which is continuous, and let $x_n$ be the sequence equal to $1$ in the $n$th entry and zero elsewhere. Then $x_n$ converges to the zero sequence componentwise, but not in $l^2$.

Comment: I am not sure if I get your counterexample. In your case $f:\ell^2→\mathbb R$ so I don't see how this shows that we can't component-wise continuity hence $(\rm C)$. Could elaborate on that a little bit?

Comment: I just misread your question, sorry about that

Comment: This should correct it.

Comment: All good. With "but not in $\ell^2$" you mean not considering the $\ell^2$-norm right?

Comment: Yes, the sequence doesn't converge to the zero sequence in the $\ell^2$ norm. Since $f$ is the identity map that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I have another question if you don't mind. Is it possible t get component-wise convergence in $(\rm C)$?

Answer (score 0):

In any metrizable topological space, sequential continuity is equivalent to topological continuity!

The space  $l_{2}$ is a normed space, hence metrizable with

$d(x,y)= \left\|x-y \right\|$. Therefore if $f$ is continuous, it is

also sequentially continuous which immediately gives the result!!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is an interesting result! Would you tell me how sequentially continuity is defined? Even better would be a book that treats this statement.

Comment: See the picture I edited in my answer!!

Comment: Thank you for your effort, really appreciate it! I am still not sure how we get the limit in $(\rm C)$ explicitly. Does it mean in the case of $\ell^2$ that $f=(f_1,f_2,...)$ and $f_i$ is one-dimensional and continuous?

Comment: You can thank me with an upvote my friend!!

Comment: Sure you deserved it! But could you explain a bit further?